# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap Error in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, real-time

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var adapter : MyTrackers.ContactAdapter?=null
    var listOfContact = ArrayList<UserContact>()
    var databaseRef:DatabaseReference?=null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    var userData = UserData(this)
    userData.loadPhoneNumber()

    databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

    //For debug only
    //dummyData()

    adapter = MyTrackers.ContactAdapter(this, listOfContact)
    lvContactList.adapter = adapter
    lvContactList.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
        parent, view, position, id ->
        val userInfo = listOfContact[position]
        UserData.myTrackers.remove(userInfo.phoneNumber)
    }

}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    refereshUsers()
}

fun refereshUsers(){
    val userData = UserData(this)
    if(userData.loadPhoneNumber()=="empty"){ //FirstTIme activity Starts
        return
    }
    databaseRef!!.child("Users").child(userData.loadPhoneNumber())
            .child("Finders").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{


                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    val td = dataSnapshot!!.value as HashMap<String,Any>
                    listOfContact.clear()

                    if(td==null){
                        listOfContact.add(UserContact("NO_USERS","Nothing"))
                        adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        return
                    }

                    for (key in td.keys){
                        listOfContact.add(UserContact("NO_NAME",key))
                    }

                }
```

I always get the above java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap in my td declaration in my onDataChange method. Whenever I try to debug based on previous stackoverflow solutions it still doesnt work can someone show me what error I am making and how will be able to make neccessary corrections.

Here is The Structure of my Database

```
 "Users" : {
    "7151418" : {
      "Finders" : "2018/03/26 20:03:02",
      "request" : "2018/03/26 20:03:02"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: Thanks I think I have it here already

Comment: Where, I cannot see it. Through database structure, I mean what you already have in your database.

Comment: Have you seen it @Alex

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states:

> [getValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue()) returns the data contained in this snapshot as native
>   types. The possible types returned are:
>
> `Boolean`
>   `String`
>   `Long`
>   `Double`
>   `Map<String, Object>`
>   `List<Object>`

So, in your case `dataSnapshot!!.value` returns a `String`.

Comment: Thanks but what should I do in that instance Sir

Comment: what value will contain, depends on your db schema. you will have to change it or evalurate the string. please set a breakpoint or add a println(dataSnapshot!!.value) to see what exaclty is going on. :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
val td = dataSnapshot!!.value as HashMap<String,Any>
```

with

```
val td = dataSnapshot!!.value as String
```

The value of `Finders` property is actually a `String` and not HashMap.